# Is there a simple conversion method for converting chrome message passing to the safari message passing syntax?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, safari6

My Chrome extension uses message passing to retrieve various values from the extension's built in localstorage area on the background page.

The thing I love about chrome message passing, is it lets you include a callback function inside the sendMessage call, like so:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);   
});
```

and the corresponding message receiving code would look like the following (example code from the Chrome extensions documentation):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

I'm trying to convert my extension to the Safari extension format, but I can't figure out how to map the Chrome sendMessage / onMessage functions to Safari's 
`safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage(name, data)` message handling functions

Is it even possible to include callback functions in Safari's dispatchMessage function call?
If not, how should I work around this limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In environments that only provide a one-way message passing system, you can always implement "message-with-callback" yourself, by associating an unique ID with every message, and storing the callbacks in a dictionary that maps these IDs to the callbacks.

At the end of this answer, I've copy-pasted the Safari-specific storage module from the source code of my cross-browser [Lyrics Here extension](https://robwu.nl/lyricshere/), which provides the following API:

- `config.getItem(key, callback)`
- `config.setItem(key, value, callback)`
- `config.removeItem(key, callback)`
- `config.clear(callback)`

The callback of `getItem` contains the value associated with the key (if found). The other callbacks receive a boolean that tells whether the operation succeeded or not.

The source code is annotated and contains snippets to handle a few edge-cases. Feel free to shoot a few questions at me if there's anything unclear.

#### config-safari.js ([AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition))

```
// Adapter for maintaining preferences (Safari 5+)
// All methods are ASYNCHRONOUS
define('config-safari', function() {
    var config = {};
    var callbacks = {};
    ['getItem', 'setItem', 'removeItem', 'clear'].forEach(function(methodName) {
        config[methodName] = function() {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            var callback = args.pop();
            var messageID = Math.random();
            callbacks[messageID] = callback;
            
            var message = {
                type: methodName,
                messageID: messageID,
                args: args
            };
            safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('config-request', message);
        };
    });
    config.init = function() {
        if (typeof safari === 'undefined') {
            // Safari bug: safari is undefined when current context is an iframe
            // and src="javascript:''"
            // This error is only expected on YouTube.
            // config.getItem is triggered in main, so we just redefine
            // it. Don't overwrite setItem, etc., so that errors are thrown
            // when these methods are used.
            config.getItem = function(key, callback){
                callback();
            };
            return;
        }
        safari.self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.name === 'config-reply') {
                var messageID = event.message.messageID;
                var callback = callbacks[messageID];
                // Check if callback exists. It may not exist when the script is
                // activated in multiple frames, because every frame receives the message
                if (callback) {
                    delete callbacks[messageID];
                    callback(event.message.result);
                }
            }
        }, true);
    };
    return config;
});
```

Fragment of global.html:

```
<script>
(function(exports) {
    var config = {};
    config.getItem = function(key, callback) {
        var result = safari.extension.settings.getItem(key);
        if (typeof result === 'string') {
            try {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
            } catch (e) {
                // Extremely unlikely to happen, but don't neglect the possibility
                console.log('config.getItem error: ' + e);
                result = undefined;
            }
        }
        callback(result);
    };
    // callback's argument: true on success, false otherwise
    config.setItem = function(key, value, callback) {
        var success = false;
        try {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
            // Safari (5.1.5) does not enforce the database quota,
            // let's enforce it manually (ok, set the quota per key, since
            // the performance issue only occur when a specific key has an outrageous high value)
            // 1 MB should be sufficient.
            if (value.length > 1e6) {
                throw new Error('QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: length=' + value.length);
            }
            safari.extension.settings.setItem(key, value);
            success = true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('config.setItem error: ' + e);
        }
        callback(success);
    };
    // callback's argument: true on success, false otherwise
    config.removeItem = function(key, callback) {
        safari.extension.settings.removeItem(key);
        callback(true);
    };
    // callback's argument: true on success, false otherwise
    config.clear = function(callback) {
        safari.extension.settings.clear();
        callback(true);
    };

    // config's message handler
    function handleConfigRequest(event) {
        var args = event.message.args;
        // Last argument: Always a callback
        args.push(function(result) {
            // Note: All of the config methods send a callback only once
            // Behavior for calling the callback twice is undefined.
            
            // Send a reply to trigger the callback at the sender's end
            event.target.page.dispatchMessage('config-reply', {
                messageID: event.message.messageID,
                result: result
            });
        });
        config[event.message.type].apply(config, args);
    }
    
    // Export
    exports.handleConfigRequest = handleConfigRequest;
})(window);
</script>
<script>
safari.application.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    switch (event.name) {
        case 'config-request':
            handleConfigRequest(event);
            break;
        /* ... other things removed ... */
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you! thats great! :) i came up with a similar solution. still working through it, I've somehow managed to create an endless message passing loop, doh! oh well im sure i will figure it out eventually. though i think i should probably try your tried and trusted method, rather than my own.

Comment: *UPDATE* aha, i managed to break out of the endless loop, yay. thanks again.